# The type in template specialization will be continue to calculate？

Tags: c++, c++11, recursion, variadic-templates

just like these code,In the template specialization defined the type,will be the type(at the label 1),the code `test_two<N+1, Max, std::size_t>` continue to match the template specialization(`struct test_two<N,Max,std::size_t>`) and caculate the type of `test_two<N+1, Max, std::size_t>` and so on?

```
template<std::size_t N, std::size_t Max, typename T>
struct test_two
{

};

template<std::size_t N, std::size_t Max>
struct test_two<N,Max,std::size_t>
{
    using type = test_two<N+1, Max, std::size_t>  //label:1
};
```

As above

Comment: @StackDanny There's no need, really. An empty pack cannot match the partial specialisation, so it will instantiate from the primary template.

Comment: maybe `using type = typename test<Args...>::type`? And `template <typename...> struct test { using type = some_type; };` for main version?

Comment: no,I just want to know whether the code  test_two<N+1, Max, std::size_t> continue to match partical specailization and caculate the type of  `test_two<N+1, Max, std::size_t>` and so on ,even if I didn't write the end conditions of the code  like `struct test_two<Max,Max,std::size_t>` ,complier can stop the recursion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The declaration `using type = test_two<N+1, Max, std::size_t>;` does not require the right-hand-side type to be complete, so it will not instantiate the definition of `test_two<N+1, Max, std::size_t>`, only its declaration. There is therefore no infinite recursion.

Comment: thanks ,but I  used the error example code ,I have updated the example code,as you say, when I define the code like test_two<0,6,std::size_t> ,then test_two<N+1, Max, std::size_t> will be continue to match the  template specailization only once,even if I not write the end conditions of the template specialization,then complier also stop the recursion？

Comment: @jackX I've updated the answer, but next time please try to post your question so that you don't have to fundamentally change it later.